# Área de recompensa desalinhada com assinatura da pergunta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Talvez [OCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder), mas efetivamente existem 3 pixeis de diferença!

[image: Captura de tela]

**Nota:** Também se verifica na imagem em cima um desalinhamento na margem esquerda entre as opções (compartilhar) quando comparado com a margem esquerda das tags + texto por cima das mesmas.

Comment: muito bom ahahahah :)

Comment: Não será por causa do `fechar(2)` @Zuul?

Comment: Ah não já vi que é por causa do `editada`.

Comment: @JorgeB. Este layout fixo deles, com medidas em `px` por todo o lado, `float` por todo o lado, `table` por todo o lado... credo!

Comment: É como eu fazia antigamente, gambiarra para centrar div's :P

Comment: Será que eles conhecem Bootstrap? :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Com ou sem Bootstrap, o importante é usar medidas relativas para que tudo se ajuste em condições :)

Comment: Estava a ser irónico :)

Comment: Estive agora a ver ao detalhe e está uma bela duma confusão, parece trabalho feito por mim a uns anos atrás :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu entendi a ironia, mas quis aproveitar para deixar um chá prá malta da SE :D

Comment: Por curiosidade fui ver o do facebook e está a mesma bosta lol

Comment: Achei que *OCD* era *Obsessão Compulsiva Digital*. Mais um transtorno da nova era... rs

Comment: Danem-se os 3 pixels!! Olha como está tudo nesse exato momento. Meu Deus que zona!

Comment: Consertaram :) Não os 3 pixels, a zona que estava ontem a noite.